# In Xamarin what's the reason for using RemoveDynamicResource before setting a DynamicResource?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

For a page I see

```
RemoveDynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty);
this.DynamicResource(BackgroundColorProperty, 
   nameof(BaseTheme.GitTrendsImageBackgroundColor));
```

So I am wondering, why it is needed to first remove the resource? Does the setting on the next line not override and remove it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the setting on the next line not override and remove it anyway

The [Element.RemoveDynamicResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.element.setdynamicresource?view=xamarin-forms) method is to remove a previously set dynamic resource. It's not necessary to call the method when updating the dynamicResource. And there is not the `Element.DynamicResource` method or it has been deprecated, try using `Element.SetDynamicResource` instead.

```
this.SetDynamicResource(ContentPage.StyleProperty, "theCustomStyle");
```

Comment: Thanks Jarvan,  apologies as the DynamicResource was an extension.  However thanks for telling me about RemoveDynamicResource.  I have been looking at a Microsoft developed app and the dev had used the RemoveDynamicResource so I just wanted to hear if anyone could think of a reason why it would be needed here.